# Need help with complex Formula with CASE() and/or IF()

Tags: reporting, formula

I have to convert this logic into Salesforce Formula.

```
IF renewalStartDate Is Less Than closeDate 
    THEN (
            IF renewalStartDate Month Quarter Number = closeDate Month Quarter Number  (AND)  renewalStartDate Year = closeDate Year
                THEN 'In Quarter' 
                ELSE 'Late Renewal'
         )
ELSE IF renewalStartDate Is Greater Than closeDate
    THEN (
            IF renewalStartDate Month Quarter Number = closeDate Month Quarter Number  (AND)  renewalStartDate Year = closeDate Year
                THEN 'In Quarter' 
                ELSE 'In Future'
    )
ELSE 'In Quarter'
```

After a couple of hours, this is my best attempt, but it's not returning the expected results.

```
IF(OpportunityLineItem.Renewal_Start__c - 1 < CLOSE_DATE,
    IF(AND(CEILING(MONTH(OpportunityLineItem.Renewal_Start__c ) - 1 / 3) == CEILING(MONTH(CLOSE_DATE)/3),
YEAR(OpportunityLineItem.Renewal_Start__c)-1 == YEAR(CLOSE_DATE)),
        'In Quarter',
        'Late Renewal'),
        IF(AND(CEILING(MONTH(OpportunityLineItem.Renewal_Start__c ) - 1 / 3) == CEILING(MONTH(CLOSE_DATE)/3),
YEAR(OpportunityLineItem.Renewal_Start__c)-1 == YEAR(CLOSE_DATE)),
            'In Quarter',
            'In Future')
)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your test case that shows observed results and explains how they differ from expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified my formula and tested before adding an embedded If and testing some more. This appears to be perfect. Will do full boundary testing at the year and quarter ends and beginnings soon.

```
IF(OpportunityLineItem.Renewal_Start__c - 1 < CLOSE_DATE,
  IF(
    AND(
      CEILING(
          MONTH(OpportunityLineItem.Renewal_Start__c ) / 3) == 
      CEILING(MONTH(CLOSE_DATE)/3),
      YEAR(OpportunityLineItem.Renewal_Start__c) == YEAR(CLOSE_DATE)),
    'In Quarter',
    'Late Renewal')
  ,IF(AND(
      CEILING(
          MONTH(OpportunityLineItem.Renewal_Start__c ) / 3) == 
      CEILING(MONTH(CLOSE_DATE)/3),
      YEAR(OpportunityLineItem.Renewal_Start__c) == YEAR(CLOSE_DATE)),
    'In Quarter',
    'In Future')
)
```

I removed '-1' from the inner IF() statemnts. That was throwing things off.